# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with jest and swiper v10

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, swiper.js

im working on react typescript app and have an issue writing unit tests for swiper v10, the swiper is working well but i got SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with jest.
[image]

i tried these configs

jest config

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  verbose: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>src/setupTests.ts'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  rootDir: './',
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

    'swiper/css': 'swiper/swiper.min.css',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```

babel config

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

Comment: Usually this message is happened when js is trying to run TS files. Thought you have set the preset to 'ts-jest'. Can you show what command you are running?

Comment: @AbrorAbdullaev
in my package.json i set the test command to "test": "jest --watch" and run it by `npm test`

Answer (score 0):

`swiper` is one of the packages that should be ignored from transformation.

In your `jest.config.js` file, add the following

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(swiper))']
```

There is also a discussion on the library's GitHub [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/discussions/4969)

Comment: unfortunately didn't work